# upgrade from Mariadb 10.2.* to 10.3.* using mariabackup?

Tags: mariadb

Anyone successfully done upgrade from 10.2 to 10.3 using mariabackup without any downtime to the cluster?

I have 3 node cluster. Node1 serves the traffic rest are for standby and quorum. I would like to upgrade them from 10.2 to 10.3.

```
10.2 -> Has xtrabackup
10.3 -> Has mariabackup
```

IST doesn't happen when I upgrade 3rd node from 10.2 to 10.3. But when I copy xtrabackup* files from 2nd node and use wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup_v2. IST works. 
When I change it to mariabackup and restart it doesn't work.

Comment: Does the failure to restart give any error messages?

Comment: For what it's worth: I've done the 10.2 -> 10.3 MariaDB Galera upgrade successfully, using `mariabackup` on both 10.2 and 10.3 nodes. It works. You need to provide a lot more detail, explaining better exactly what you've done and the error messages you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a 3node cluster.  Am upgrading node3,node2 and node1.

```
apt-get install  mariadb-backup-10.2
```

is required for 2nd node(donor node) to initially pick mariabackup using 10.2.16.

This will ensure /usr/bin/mariabackup file on 2nd node(donor).

3rd node should have below values.

```
wsrep_sst_method=mariabackup  
wsrep_sst_donor="donor/2ndnode"
```

When upgrading 2nd node. You may upgrade mariadb-backup-10.2 to mariadb-backup-10.3 as well on 2nd node.

```
wsrep_sst_method=mariabackup  
wsrep_sst_donor="donor/3rdnode"
```

Before upgrading 1st node.  Route the traffic from 1st node to node2. And proceed upgrade. It will have in 10.3 for both mariadb-server and mariadb-backup.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what mariabackup is for. You backup and restore in the same "major" version (where "major" means it just means first 2 number of the version). If you need an upgrade, this is what mysql_upgrade is for.

Comment: It doesn't upgrade with xtrabackup. You have to use mariabackup to upgrade to 10.3.

Comment: yes, mariabackup does not *upgrade*. It was not designed to handle multiple versions. It can handle own version. It can prepare backup, from a matching version, this is what I'm trying to tell.